# extracting standardized coefficients from lm in R

Tags: r, regression, lm, beta, standardized

My apologies for the dumb question...but I can't seem to find a simple solution

I want to extract the standardized coefficients from a fitted linear model (in R)
there must be a simple way or function that does that. can you tell me what is it?

EDIT (following some of the comments below):
I should have probably provided more contextual information about my question. I was teaching an introductory R workshop for a bunch of psychologists. For them, a linear model without the ability to get standardized coefficients is as if you didn't run the model at all (ok, this is a bit of an exaggeration, but you get the point). When we've done some regressions this was their first question, which (my bad) I didn't anticipate (I'm not a psychologist). Of course I can program this myself, and of course I can look for packages that do it for me. But at the same time, I do think that this is kind of a basic and common required feature of linear models, that on the spot, I thought there should be a basic function that does it without a need to install more and more packages (which is perceived as a difficulty for beginners). So I asked (and this was also an opportunity to show them how to get help when they need it).

My apologies for those who think I asked a stupid question, and my many thanks for those who took the time to answer it.

Comment: try this function `stdcoeff <- function (MOD)  {b <- summary(MOD)$coef[-1, 1] ;    sx <- sd(MOD$model[-1]);     sy <- sd(MOD$model[1]);     beta <- b * sx/sy   ;  return(beta) }` where `MOD` is your model produced by `lm` function, so you''ll use it as `stdcoeff(lm(...))` (I didn't write it, just found on the net, so not posting as an answer)

Comment: I liked [this approach](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/standardizing7.pdf). It rescales the input variables by two times the standard deviation for easy interpretation. Its `standardize`function can be found in the `arm` package.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, where do you see the solution to this question in the help files?  Whether @DavidArenburg's comment or the `QuantPsyc::lm.beta` answer below is correct depends on what the OP means by "standardized" (which they didn't specify)

Comment: The help files clearly locate the coefficients `lm` generates. Anyone who's qualified to do statistical analysis should know the equations which relate the various values `lm` returns to whatever parameters they wish to calculate.  I'm not just being snooty here: people who blindly trust some computer program to do everything for them will never learn to evaluate the quality (accuracy, etc) of the answer they get.  It's like using `confint` in Excel without ever knowing that it's calculated at the 95% level.

Comment: oops, I was actually wrong about "several definitions" -- sorry.  I read @DavidArenburg's comment too quickly (and didn't remember that `lm` stored the model frame there); his comment is the same as the internal code in `QuantPsyc::lm.beta`

Comment: whut evvarrr..  sorry for being a grouch here.

Comment: See my edit in the body of the question for some responses to the comments above. many thanks to those who contributed.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

There is a convenience function in the `QuantPsyc` package for that, called `lm.beta`. However, I think the easiest way is to just standardize your variables. The coefficients will then automatically be the standardized "beta"-coefficients (i.e. coefficients in terms of standard deviations).

For instance,

```
 lm(scale(your.y) ~ scale(your.x), data=your.Data)
```

will give you the standardized coefficient.

**Are they really the same?** The following illustrates that both are identical:

```
library("QuantPsyc")
mod <- lm(weight ~ height, data=women)
coef_lmbeta <- lm.beta(mod)

coef_lmbeta
> height 
  0.9955 

mod2 <- lm(scale(weight) ~ scale(height), data=women)
coef_scale <- coef(mod2)[2]

coef_scale
> scale(height) 
  0.9955 

all.equal(coef_lmbeta, coef_scale, check.attributes=F)
[1] TRUE
```

which shows that both are identical, as they should be.

**How to avoid clumsy variable names?**
In case you don't want to deal with these clumsy variable names such as `scale(height)`, one option is to standardize the variables outside the `lm` call in the dataset itself. For instance,

```
women2 <- lapply(women, scale) # standardizes all variables

mod3 <- lm(weight ~ height, data=women2)
coef_alt <- coef(mod3)[2]
coef_alt
> height 
  0.9955 

all.equal(coef_lmbeta, coef_alt)
[1] TRUE
```

**How do I standardize multiple variables conveniently?** In the likely event that you don't want to standardize all variables in your dataset, you could pick out all that occur in your formula. For instance, referring to the `mtcars`-dataset now (since `women` only contains `height` and `weight`):

Say the following is the regression model I want to estimate:

```
 modelformula <- mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat + qsec
```

We can use the fact that `all.vars` gives me a vector of the variable names.

```
 all.vars(modelformula)
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "qsec"
```

We can use this to subset the dataset accordingly. For instance,

```
mycars <- lapply(mtcars[, all.vars(modelformula)], scale)
```

will give me a dataset in which all variables have been standardized. Linear regressions using `mycars` will now give standardized betas. Please make sure that standardizing all these variables makes sense, though!

**Potential issue with only one variable:** In case you model formula only contains one explanatory variable and you are working with the built-in dataframes (and not with tibbles), the following adjustment is advisable (credits go to @JerryT in the comments):

```
mycars <- lapply(mtcars[, all.vars(modelformula), drop=F], scale)
```

This is because when you extract only one column from a standard data frame, R retuns a vector instead of a dataframe. `drop=F` will prevent this from happening. This also won't be a problem if e.g. `tibbles` are used. See e.g.

```
class(mtcars[, "mpg"])
[1] "numeric"
class(mtcars[, "mpg", drop=F])
[1] "data.frame"
library(tidyverse)
class(as.tibble(mtcars)[, "mpg"])
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

**Another issue with missing values** in the dataframe (credits go again to @JerryT in the comments): By default, R's `lm` removes all *rows* where at least one column is missing. `scale`, on the other hand, would take all values that are non-missing, even if an observation has a missing value in a different column. If you want to mimick the action of `lm`, you may want to first drop all rows with missing values, like so:

```
all_complete <- complete.cases(df)
df[all_complete,]
```

Comment: note that this is more or less what `arm::standardize` does (although it offers some flexibility as to whether the response is scaled or not, and does some fancier/non-standard stuff with dummies for categorical predictors).  The advantage of the `lm.beta` approach is that it doesn't require re-fitting the model.

Comment: The `dplyr` alternative to standardizing multiple variables would be: `mycars <- mtcars %>% mutate_each_(funs(scale), all.vars(model.formula))`, I believe.

Comment: make sure you drop na (if there is missing) before scale
also, lapply(mtcars[, all.vars(modelformula), drop=F], scale)  in case there is only one variable in modelformula

There is also lm.beta package which does the same

Comment: @JerryT I believe `scale` can handle missing values, but that is a very good point about `drop=F`. I will include it in my answer to warn people about it!

Comment: @coffeinjunky You are such an excellent teacher here and explain things very well. I think lapply applies scale columwise, so for example, cyl has NA in row 1, disp has NA in row 2. When one do lm, both row 1 and 2 will be removed due to NA, but scale will only remove row 1 for cyl, row 2 for disp. So I think it is better to do drop na before scale, to be consistent with lm's na.action (assuming na.exclude or na.omit)

Comment: @JerryT Fair point. Hadn't thought about that! Thanks for the explanation. Will update in a short while!

Comment: The object `mycars` is defined in that line, i.e. `mycars[] <- ...` will fail unless you have instantiated it before, and `lm` will work just fine with the list. If you want to keep it as a dataframe, you can always wrap it up in `data.frame()`. In general though, there is a lot to be said about proper workflow and handling of R objects. I really wish StackOverflow answers would be intended as tutorials for new beginners.

Answer (score 7):

Package `lm.beta` has several functions to work with standardised coefficients, including `lm.beta()` which requires an `lm` object:

```
res <- lm(y~x)
lm.beta(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `colnames(data)` with `lapply` or `sapply`.
For example:

```
lapply(data[, colnames(data)], scale)
```

Comment: This is pretty inconvenient if any of your input is not scalar.